# best way to prepare for digg effect

Tags: scalability, high-availability, high-load

I have a web site which will be featured in a place which will send a large peak of one-time traffic in a couple of weeks.

The server hosting the website also hosts the control panel my customers use.

The website part is simple and mostly static. But it includes a wordpress blog.

My question
How and where can I put or cache the website and blog so that it will make it through traffic peak?
For example, is it possible to host the pages on Amazon s3 so that they will be accessible via the regular urls on my domains without going through the server ?

Comment: Unless this is asking about programmatic ways to handle server load, I'd suggest this is better suited to http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com, although it can't be migrated currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look into the following things:

- [Varnish](http://varnish-cache.org/), or another reverse proxy, to cache the blog.
- [DNS round robin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS), to distribute load.